# What is the appropriate way to statistically analyse diversity indexes?

Tags: r, anova, ecology, diversity, vegan

I have been working with a soil-derived viral metagenomic data set and am looking for advice on the appropriate statistical approach to the results.

I have 2 different sample areas. Within both areas I have 3 replicate sites. Within each of these replicate sites, I have 4 samples. Totaling 24 samples.

Within each of these samples, I have produced a list of all the virus fragments within the soil. To work out a relative abundance I have done the following: Divided the number of reads by the length to produce a reads per kilobase (RPK) value. I have then produced a normalised value counts/transcripts per million (CPM/TPM) by dividing the RPK of each fragment by the sum of all RPK values in the sample divided by one million. This gives a representative abundance of each fragment, normalised to the length and total reads in each sample. This is following the current accepted guidelines for viral ecology metrics, more information could be found here if required - https://www.rna-seqblog.com/rpkm-fpkm-and-tpm-clearly-explained/.

On this CPM/TPM number I have produced a variety of ecological metrics within the R 'vegan' package, including Shannon diversity, Simpsons Diversity, species richness and pielous_eveness.

From here I am struggling to work out what is the appropriate statistic analysis of these ecological metrics results would be. What I need to do is to generate statistics on the differences between all samples, samples within each replicate, replicates within each area and finally between the two areas.

For note, I have carried out Shapiro-wilk normality tests on the produced ecological metrics from each replicate sites, as well as the combined 12 samples for each sample area (3 replicate sites). All have returned a normal distribution, although I am conscious that the N is low for these.

It is my belief that perhaps an ANOVA followed by a post-hoc tukey would be the best way to carry out this analysis. However, being honest I am not confident with my own assessment as the statistical side of research is my weaker side by far!

Feel free to ask any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would use Hill numbers in the iNext R package

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this seems very useful!

Comment: Hill numbers are also available in vegan. Have been since 2001.